# Solution of $mx''+cx'+kx=|\sin(t)|$ using Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, matlab, transformation

Starting with $$m\ddot x + c\dot x +kx = |\sin(t)|, $$

I get $$X(s) = \frac{1+e^{-\pi s}}{(s^2+1)(1-e^{-\pi s})(ms^2+cs+k)}.$$

When trying to use inverse Laplace tranform in MATLAB `ilaplace()`, the results is both complex and contains the floor-function, so I can't plot it.

How do I solve this?

Note that $m$, $c$ and $k$ are known constants.

I have also tried using dsolve, but this doesn't work either. Is it possible to use dsolve to solve this equation.

Comment: It is not that surprising that the floor function appears as $|\sin t|=(-1)^{floor(x/\pi)}\sin(t)=\sin(t-\floor(t/\pi)\pi)=\sin(t\mod \pi)=\sin(\{t/\pi\}\pi$, the last using the fractional part.

Comment: Maple `dsolve` :$x \left( t \right) ={{\rm e}^{1/2\,{\frac { \left( -c+\sqrt {{c}^{2}-4
\,km} \right) t}{m}}}}{\it \_C2}+{{\rm e}^{-1/2\,{\frac { \left( c+
\sqrt {{c}^{2}-4\,km} \right) t}{m}}}}{\it \_C1}-{\frac {{\it signum}
 \left( \sin \left( t \right)  \right)  \left(  \left( -k+m \right) 
\sin \left( t \right) +\cos \left( t \right) c \right) }{{c}^{2}+{k}^{
2}-2\,km+{m}^{2}}}
$ where: ${\it signum} \left( \sin \left( t \right)  \right) ={\frac {\sin
 \left( t \right) }{ \left| \sin \left( t \right)  \right| }}
$